# How to print date in MM/DD/YYYY formate in unix?

Tags: date, unix, echo

I'm new to unix and I'm trying to run print the date using:

`` echo "Purchase date: `date`" ``

but I keep getting the date in the format

> Purchase date: Fri Oct  2 12:21:26 EDT 2020

but I'm trying to get it in the format of MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search will show you lots of options but I believe you want something like: **~$ date +%m/%d/%Y**

**~$ 10/02/2020**

%[a-z] represents formatting options.

- %m - month (01..12)
- %d - day of month
- %Y - Full Year
- '/' - Delimiter

You can see all of the date formatting options by using the help command:
**~$ date --help**